# ggplot and ggvis for numeric vector in R

Tags: r, vector, ggplot2, numeric, ggvis

I have a numeric vector `counts` which stores a total count of a column from several tables `list`.

so `head(counts)` gives:

```
head(counts)
## [1] 1000 1000   40 1000 1000  624
```

1000 is value for table1, 1000 for table2, 40 for table 3 and so on.

and `head(list)` gives:

```
head(list)
## [1] "table1"        "table2"    "table3"
## [4] "table"         "table"     "table6"
```

when I do `barplot(counts)` I get a barplot. But I can't draw a barplot using `ggvis` or `ggplot`. For ggplot I get this error:

```
ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class numeric.
```

so I converted it to `data.frame` and store it as a new variable:

```
newdata <- data.frame(counts,list)
```

when I did `head(newdata)` I got this:

```
##   counts             list
## 1   1000             table1
## 2   1000             table2
## 3     40             table3
```

but when I try to draw a barplot using ggvis I get an error:

```
ggvis(newdata, props(x = ~list, y = ~counts, y2 = 0)) +
  mark_rect(props(width := 10))
error in new_prop.default... : unknown input to pro: list(property = "x" ...)
```

and if I draw a ggplot `ggplot(newdata, aes(x = list, y = counts))` I get a blank graph. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

barplot with `ggplot`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(newdata, aes(x = list, y = counts)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

barplot with `ggvis`

```
library(ggvis)
newdata %>% ggvis(~list, ~counts) %>% layer_bars()
```

[image]